# How to prevent button clicks in a MS Access Form_A when Form_B is correctly displayed modal over Form_A

Tags: vba, forms, ms-access, modal-dialog

I realized while I was typing up this question what the problem might be and was then able to solve it.  So, I have posted the question and then the answer in case it helps someone else.

I am using MS Access 2016.  I have a Form_A that displays a menu of buttons--each button takes the user to a distinct form to perform whatever functions the user needs to perform.  For example, one Form_A menu button could be [Add Clients] while another button could be [Add Staff], etc.

When the user first logs into the system, I use VBA code to do a number of "housecleaning" functions.  Form_A and the buttons are visible, but I have made a Form_B that is a small dialog that shows the word "Working" with animated "..." while the VBA in Form_A does the housecleaning.

**The problem that I cannot solve is that even though I have set Form_B's "Pop Up" property to "Yes" and its "Modal" property to "Yes", the user can still click buttons on the Form_A menu which then execute while Form_B is still doing its housecleaning.**

**I thought setting Form_B to modal should prevent button clicks on Form_A from getting registered.**

More details:

1. In the *Form_Load* event, Form_A calls "housekeeping" code that resides in a Module.  That module has a Public Sub called "RemakeTables."  The RemakeTables code uses `DoCmd.OpenForm "Form_B"` to display the "Working" dialog.
2. The RemakeTables code calls several other Public subs.  Between each call to the other Public subs, a `DoEvents` is called which allows for the "Working" dialog to animate the "..." (i.e., cycle between "Working", "Working.", "Working..", and "Working...").

My hunch is that the `DoEvents` is what is allowing clicks to get registered in Form_A.

How should I be doing this so that clicks cannot be registered while the Form_B "Working" dialog is showing but can still be animated?

Answer (score 0):

As I was typing up the question, it occurred to me that the main problem was that the subs and functions I was calling during "housekeeping" used the `DoEvents` action to allow the Form_B "Working" dialog to update/animate.  However, `DoEvents` also allows mouse clicks to register.

So, how to prevent the problem?

**Include the "housekeeping" calls in the *Form_Open* event rather than the *Form_Load* event** because the *Form_Open* event occurs first, before the *Form_Load* and before the form is displayed, so, there will not be any buttons visible to click if the "housekeeping" code is called in *Form_Open*.

Hope this helps someone else who might have had a similar problem.